# AttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'remark_set'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new to django, was following a tutorial and trying to use 'model_set.all()' but I don't understand the error. I tried changing it to 'project_content_type.remark_set.all()' (thinking it's an error with the related name.

Error:

```
response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lavis\Desktop\aai\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lavis\Desktop\aai\base\views.py", line 80, in project
    project = project.remark_set.all()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'remark_set'
```

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    #p_id = 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    totalamount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    payments_todate = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated','-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Remark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,related_name='project_content_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

views.py

```
def project(request, pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    remark_made = project.remark_set.all()
    context = {'project':project, 'remark_made':remark_made}
    return render(request, 'base/project.html',context)
```

Answer (score 2):

you define `related_name='project_content_type'`in model Remark, so you need to change

```
remark_made = project.project_content_type.all()
```

`related_name` defines the name of the related manager. If you remove it, default `Model + "_set"` is used (`remark_set` in your case).